# Creating "are you sure?" popup window by using html only

Tags: html, forms, popup, submit

Assume I have a html from, and it contain some submit type. I want to create a "are you sure" popup window that will appear when user click submit button. 
My question is that is there any way to create it by using "only" html, not using javascript or any other?

Comment: You need to use javascript's "prompt". HTML doesn't provide anything like that.

Comment: PHP is a pre-processor language that generates HTML that is then sent to the browser. You would still need javascript in order to create a popup window as that is done by the browser itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### HTML only is possible, but not without a postback

Scenario that could work without javascript:

1. You have your form with submit button
2. User clicks (and submits) the form
3. You display another form with *are you sure?* form (that contains **Yes** and **No** buttons as well as hidden fields of the first form that will make it possible to do the action required on the original data
4. functionality that executes the action and goes back to whatever required.

**This would be completely Javascript free**, but it would require several postbacks.

This kind of thing is usually done on the client with a Javascript `confirm()` function ([here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yaxm/)) or **lately with a more user friendly modal dialog** provided by many different client libraries or their plugins.

### When to choose the script free version?

If you know your clients are going to be very basic ones (ie. vast majority of your users will access your application using clients like Opera Mini that's not able to run scripts at all). But in all other cases it's much better to do this using Javascript. It will be faster, easier to develop and much more user friendly. Not to mention that it will put less strain on your server as well since certain parts will execute on the client without the need of any server processing.

Comment: I agree, but I'd like to add that most Web 2.0 sites do not use confirm(), but emulate this with DOM manipulation and javascript plugins such as the jquery ui dialog. This has the advantage of maintaining a consitent look & feel across your website, including the confirmation boxes.

Comment: @Adrian: The same thing is mentioned in my answer as well (just after confirm JSFiddle example). Let me emphasize it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Despite of the new features in HTML 5, HTML is still a markup language, not a programming language. In order to express dynamic behavior (such as an "are you sure?" box), you need to use a programming language.

Javascript would be the most obvious choice for this, but you could also do it with frameworks that can get you around writing Javascript by hand (for example ASP.NET).

**Edit:** Actually it appears that it would theoretically possible to do this with without Javascript or other frameworks.  As I just learned, [HTML 5 + CSS 3 seems to be turing complete](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2011/03/08/breaking-news-htmlcss-is-turing-complete/). But this is hardly relevant to this question.

Comment: @Ibrahim: I'm not a php developer, but I bet there are Frameworks for php that offer this kind of feature.

Comment: No, you can't make your browser create a popup window or dialog box with PHP, but PHP can aide you with this in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to ask for a confirmation, but it will not be in a "popup window". The creation of the "popup window" requires javascript/other language.

It will be:

1. Request (first form)
2. POST
3. Response (confirmation form)
4. POST
5. Response (outcome message)

You can create a form with all hidden elements containing the data from the first form and a "Yes" and "No" button below the "Are you sure?" text. You can use PHP sessions to avoid the hidden form elements. If there is a lot of data or confidential data or you do not want to re-validate the data from the second form, use sessions. Make sure you validate the data from either form before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm like .. 10 years late. But for anyone still wondering I thought I could be of some help!
What I did for this exact problem was make sure I had multiple "divs" in my code. For me specifically, I had two main ones.
First, one whose id="main", and another whose id="popup" with the 'visible' property initially set to 'false' for the popup div.

Then, on whichever event you're looking for (button click for example) you'll simply set `main.Visible = false` and `popup.Visible = true`, then you could have more buttons in your popup (yes, no, cancel, confirm, etc.) which do the exact same thing, but in reverse!

**The most important thing to make sure of is that you have the 'runat="server"' property in your divs so that you can access them in your CS code**

Hope this was helpful! :)